# Algorithm to draw waveform from audio

Tags: c++, algorithm, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to draw a waveform from a raw audio file. I demuxed/decoded an audio file using FFmpeg and I have those informations: samples buffer, the size of the samples buffer, the duration of the audio file (in seconds), sample rate (44100, 48000, etc), sample size, sample format (uint8, int16, int32, float, double), and the raw audio data itself.

Digging on the Internet I found this algorithm (more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dawate/archive/2009/06/25/intro-to-audio-programming-part-4-algorithms-for-different-sound-waves-in-c.aspx)):

White Noise:

[image: White Noise]

**The Algorithm**

> All you need to do is randomize every sample from –amplitude to
>   amplitude. We don’t care about the number of channels in most cases so
>   we just fill every sample with a new random number.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
short randomValue = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++)
{
    randomValue = Convert.ToInt16(rnd.Next(-amplitude, amplitude));
    data.shortArray[i] = randomValue;
}
```

It's really good but I don't want to draw that way, but this way:

[image: audacity]

Is there any algorithm or idea of how I can be drawing using the informations that I have?

Comment: You appear to be trying to use wave form **generating** algorithms when you already have your wave form. So it sounds to me like you need to do nothing at all.

Comment: @Galik - What you mean with "you already have your wave form"? The only thing I have is the informations about the raw file listed above, now I'm looking for an algorithm to draw the wave form using those informations.

Comment: Well the algorithms you linked have nothing to do with drawing the wave. They generate the wave. You generated your wave using ffmpeg to convert raw sound data. So you don't need a generator. I think maybe what you need is some kind of GUI framework that allows you to draw stuff on the screen.

Comment: @Galik - I see. I can use Qt with Canvas or OpenGL, but that is exactly the point, drawing those informations using Canvas or OpenGL.

Comment: I think you need to pick a framework and then ask a question specifically for it because they all work a little differently.

Comment: First, you need to obtain the samples from the audio file, not just the metadata. It sounds like you don't have that yet...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you need to determine where on the screen each sample will end up.

```
int x = x0 + sample_number * (xn - x0) / number_of_samples;
```

Now, for all samples with the same `x`, determine the min and the max separately for positive and negative values. Draw a vertical line, a dark one from negative max to positive max, then a light one from negative min to positive min over the top of it.

Edit: thinking about this a little more, you probably want to use an average instead of the min for the inner lines.

Answer (score 32):

**Explanation for Everybody**

I am a developer of a dj app and was searching for similar answers.
So, I will explain the common techniques to visualize music waveforms you may see in audio software like Audacity.

There are 3 common approaches to visualizing these waveforms: Samples, Average, and RMS (root mean square).

1. In a Samples approach, the actual music points are presented in a graph.  This could be an array of raw audio data like the points you see when you zoom into the waveform in Audacity.
2. Next, Average is the most commonly used approach. Let's assume you are displaying a 3 minute song on screen. So, a single point on screen must display at least 100ms (approximately) of the song which internally has many more raw audio points. So, for displaying this song, we calculate the average of all points within each 100ms duration or window. Audacity, for example, displays this as the big, dark blue waveform.
3. Finally, RMS is similar to Average. However, here, we compute the root mean square within each window. Audacity, for example, displays this as the small, light blue waveform inside the larger, dark blue waveform.

Now, let's determine how to calculate these waveforms.

1. For Samples, first, decode the song to generate raw data and to create raw samples/points. Now, based on the format of points, normalize them into a range between -1 to 1. For example, if the format is 16-bit, divide all the points by 32768 (the maximum range for 16 bit numbers) and then draw the points.
2. For Average, first, add the absolute value of all points. Then, multiply by 2 and then take the average. Here is an example:

```
//samples is the array and nb_samples is the length of array
float sum = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < nb_samples ; i++){
    if(samples[i] < 0)
        sum += -samples[i];
    else
        sum += samples[i];
}
float average_point = (sum * 2) / nb_samples; //average after multiplying by 2
//now draw this point
```

3. For RMS, first, square every sample.  Then, take the sum, calculate the mean, and, finally, compute sqaure root.  Here is a programming example:

```
//samples is the array and nb_samples is the length of array
float squaredsum = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < nb_samples ; i++){
    squaredsum += samples[i] * samples[i]; // square and sum
}
float mean = squaredsum / nb_samples; // calculated mean
float rms_point = Math.sqrt(mean); //now calculate square root in last
//now draw this point
```

Please note the samples are the array of points for calculating the point/pixel for a particular duration of a song. For example, if you want to draw 1 minute of a song's data in 60 pixels, the samples array will be the array of all points within 1 second; i.e. the amount of audio points to be displayed in 1 pixel.

I hope this will help clarify the concepts about audio waveforms.

Comment: After doing some research and experimentation myself, I found that calculating the max and min values per point (window of samples from the original file) and drawing the max upwards, the min downwards (I plan to post the algorithm as answer as well) looks closest to all audio software I tried (Reaper, Audacity, Reason, Live). When following the "average approach", the waveform shrinks considerably and I have to scale it up again, go get nice results, which look considerably different to the min/max approach or what I saw in common DAWs.

Comment: Will note that `squaredsum` being a float here is important - I was trying to implement this myself and was having issues with the rms waveform disappearing because I was overflowing `int32 squaredsum`

Comment: @CraftedCart In my opinion drawing maximum value from samples and drawing the rms value are the 2 most important waveforms. The average method is for complete song waveform(used by only few softwares), but mostly rms is used for complete song waveform (without the sqrt part)

Answer (score 6):

I think you are referring to a waveform described here.

http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/audacity_waveform.html

I have not read the whole page.  But each vertical bar represents a window of waveform samples.  The dark blue are the maximum positive and and minimum negative values in that window (I think).  And the light blue is the RMS which is root mean squared.  http://www.mathwords.com/r/root_mean_square.htm.  (basically you square the values within each window, take an average, and then square root.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "maximum positive and and minimum negative" – I did some experimentation and this looks the closest.

Comment: Jup, found it in the source: `WaveClip::GetWaveDisplay`: https://github.com/audacity/audacity/blob/master/src/WaveClip.cpp - They calculate min, max and RMS per window for display.

Comment: I think now it's in https://github.com/audacity/audacity/blob/master/src/tracks/playabletrack/wavetrack/ui/WaveformCache.cpp

Answer (score 3):

## showwavespic

`ffmpeg` can draw a waveform with the [`showwavespic`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwavespic) filter.

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "showwavespic=split_channels=1" output.png
```

See [`showwavespic` filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwavespic) for options.

## showwaves

You can also make a video of the live waveform with the [`showwaves`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwavespic) filter.

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"showwaves=s=600x240:mode=line:split_channels=1,format=yuv420p[v]"  \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

See [`showwaves` filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwavespic) for options.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to export the waveform data (not the pcm data but the samples with RMS ran through them). I manually calculate RMS from the pcm data but it is pretty slow so I was thinking ffmpeg might have a filter for it.

Comment: @MehmetEfeAkça Should be asked as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice program [audiowaveform](https://github.com/bbcrd/audiowaveform) from BBC R&D that does what you want, you might consult their sources.

Comment: For sure it will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom graphs simply include a longer time span, so if you increased your numSamples you would get a tighter graph.  But with white noise you wont see the peaks and troughs that you will find in normal sounds / music.

So if you can increase your sample size, or at least increase your sample period (x-axis) you will start to emulate the bottom charts.  Use two of them to get the stereo effect.

Answer (score 1):

The second waveform is probably a column approximation of a simple zig zag graph.

Every column is a line from the previous sample amplitude to the current sample amplitude.

So read all the samples into a canvas or texture as a pre-test as dots, then, once you have done that you can do two cases, make bars instead of dots, draw upwards to last sample or upwards to this sample depending on whichever was higher, as long as you draw a line between to two. That makes sure that the waveform is small with low energies between next samples and high with high energies.

You can alias it and measure multiple samples, it just depends what hardware you are running on, if you want to read 1000ds of samples and make a giant 2d array representation of the wave and then alias it downwards into a smaller displayable image or if you want to just run 512 samples only and update fast. with 2d canvas in programs it should be fast to make detailed waveforms with more than 512 samples.

... a different option is same as the grey waveform in the other answer, draw absolute value as lines from +current sample to -current sample.

it helps to average multiple samples i.e. ever 4 samples or get max of every 4 samples to have a less erratic graph, it's a kid of fast aliasing.

Comment: I did some code based on using a bar graph to approximate a zig zag graph, i found the canvas draw functions to be a bit slow for memory, i found that if you divide 44100 by 8 or 16 , use max of every 16 samples, it still looks very clear, SR is then 2900 per second, it's fine, and saves memory... i found that graphics card was much faster to display vertices than attempting to do it in a textre, so i made a grapy of flat polygons as lines, in 2d canvas code it's much faster anyway you probably would miss that much compared ot sending ot graphics shadre to make polys. dx11 code is onunityforum