# Algorithm to draw a waveform

Tags: winapi, wav, direct2d

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663494/algorithm-to-draw-waveform-from-audio) to draw the waveform, I 'm looking do it efficiently. Perhaps it's more an opinion-based question but I'm not sure of the best way I can handle it.  I have a waveform and a set of positive/negative peaks (at first load, grabbed from the audio and cached in a peak database) for it and I am about to draw it with Direct2D.

I can draw it by:

- Raw line drawing of the peaks depending on the current zoom level line by line. This ought to be the slowest method but with maximum quality.
- Caching bitmaps for a set of defined zoom levels and upscaling in case of larger zoom (lowers quality) and lots of memory used especially for when lots of waveforms are loaded - this is a sequencer and I may have 100 waves loaded.
- Drawing with a ID2D1Geometry created from the peaks I get. The more peaks I use in the geometry, the slowest geometry drawing I will get. The less peaks I use, the more sparse waveform I have in big zooms.
- Ther's a concept in Windows 8+ called [Geometry Realizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/geometry-realizations-overview) which, as I undesrtand, are semi-rasterizations of the geometry so I 'd create a few geometry realizations (exponentially scaled?) that would cover various zoom areas.

From your experience, what would be some almost-optimal performance method?

Comment: Are you having performance problems with your first algorithm? Everything should happen in GPU, so it should be quite fast. You could also use a shader, eg: https://shader.how/to/draw-a-sine-wave/

Comment: @SimonMourier you are right, but isn't a bunch of DrawLine() calls slower than one DrawGeometry call?

Comment: Difficult to say upfront. What happens behind the scene is the CPU (Direct2D/3D) builds a command list (what's between D2D's BeginDraw & EndDraw) and pushes this to the GPU. Geometry Realizations should be better since it caches CPU <-> GPU transfers but is it worth the effort? IMHO, only performance measurement could actually say.